# Confustion regarding usage of "that" vs "that the" in sentence

Tags: optional-that

I am confused on the correct usage of "that" vs "that the", and with my Google-fu being weak on how to find more information on this, I am stuck in trying to figure out which of one the following sentences is correct:

1. *I noticed **that the** build was failing.*
2. *I noticed **the** build was failing.*

Comment: The are both correct. The use of *that* here is optional. (Although your first sentence should use *noticed*, not *notice*.)

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example

> I noticed the build was failing.

can be thought of as including an implied "that"

> I noticed [that] the build was failing.

"the build was failing" is the subject of the sentence, it is the thing that was noticed. "that the build was failing" is a relative clause, which serves to provide the subject. Therefor, the example sentence "I noticed the build was failing." includes a [reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) also serving as the subject. Such clauses can be confusing, but are perfectly acceptable.

The two forms, with and without "that", have the same meaning.